# Why is my save file dialog opening twice when it is run?

Tags: c#, winforms, save

I have a small application that needs to save to contents of a rich text box as a text file upon a button click.  What I currently have is

```
//save button logic
private void saveBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //set up new SaveFileDialog
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save a text File";

    //prompt the user
    DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    //if they select save write the contents of the RTB to a text file
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

It seems like a pretty straight forward piece of code, but I can't figure out why the dialog opens twice.

Comment: Have you attached the event handler twice?  Perhaps once though the designer and once though code?  If you debug the program do you see the entire event handler executed twice?

Comment: Can you add the code that connects the button to the handler to your question?

Comment: @Servy he is creating a new instance with code,how he can attach same event handler?

Comment: @Selman22 he's creating a new instance of the dialogue, Servy is referring to registering the `saveBtn1_Click` method to respond to more than 1 event.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal ah, right.I'm confused =)

Comment: Well there we go, that was the problem. Thanks for the quick response Servy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just expanding Servy's comment into an answer because I suspect his diagnosis is correct. I'm going to give some simple suggestions for diagnosing/finding the problem. Firstly, you can put a break point in the event handler, if you're taken into that event handler twice then that's obviously the problem. The other solution (without even running) is simply to right click on the method name and select "find all references" this will give you list of all the references to the this method within your code. I'm guessing you will find 3; the method itself, the place where you expect to be registering it, and the place you were you don't. Remove the one and your problem will go away.

Comment: Answers are a place to post *solutions* to a problem, not a place to help *diagnose* a problem.  That's what comments are for.

Comment: @Servy yeah but I'd give about 10-1 odds that your diagnosis is correct so I may as well explain how to fix the problem. Fixing the problem is as simple as removing a line of code but he hasn't posted his entire solution (an I wouldn't want him to) so it's not like I can go find the line to remove and say "In somefile.cs you register that method again, remove line 218 and your problem goes away." I agree it's not an ideal answer, do you think a comment would be more appropriate? I would imagine there are plenty of readers who might learn something about VS from the answer.

Comment: Servy was correct and your answer does solve the problem I happened to have. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest answer: you called the save dialog() twice in your code. Remove the second one and your issue will clear up.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this. From what i can se it's only once the show dialog is invoked and it's only once it's written to a file..

Answer (score 0):

Because you are used twice.
Thisa is simple excample for you

```
SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
save.DefaultExt = "zip";
save.Filter = "zip faylı (*.zip)|*.7z|Hamısı(*.*)|*.*";
save.ShowDialog(); // this is first using

if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // and second using save.ShowDialog()
{
    // yours code here
}
```